# Why am I getting &#39; when AJAX saving (and repopulating) my form in Django

Tags: python, json, django, utf-8, ascii

I'm saving a draft of my form using AJAX (and a bit of Angular).

```
<!-- index.html -->

...
<input id="id_title" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Question Title" type="text" value="" required />
...

<script>

    app.controller("addQuestionCtrl", function($http) {

        $scope.title = '{% if form.title.value is not None %}{{ form.title.value }}{% endif %}';
        ...

        $interval(function() {
            ...
            data = {title:''+$scope.title, ...};
            $http.post("{% url 'save_draft' %}", data).then(function(response) {
                ...
            }, function failureCallback(error) {
                ...
            });
        }, 10000);

    });

</script>
```

This is all works fine and sends a `'` as a `'`. In my `view.py` I convert the data and store it in the session:

```
def save_draft(request):
    ....
    posted = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    ...
    request.session['draft'] = {
        'title': posted.get('title', None),
        ...
    }
```

and then populate the relevant fields when the page loads

```
def question_add(request):
    ....
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ....
    else:
        draft_question = request.session.get('draft', False)
        if draft_question:
            form = QuestionAddForm(initial={
                'title':draft_question['title'],
                ...
            })
```

Unfortunately this turns this

[image]

into this

[image]

it's not an encoding issue on the client end as the field renders as

```
 <input id="id_title" name="title" ng-model="title" ... value="&#39;title in quotes&#39;" />
```

I'm not to sure why this is happening :(

Comment: You should instead implement json renderer method in form class and return data that is possible to parse with js on the template side.

Comment: Any chance you could expand on that!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do instead (this is only draft code):

```
class QuestionAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...

    def draft_json(self, request):
        # use attribute or pass request to form init method
        draft_data = request.session.get('draft', False)
        return json.dumps(draft_data)


# in your view
context['draft_json'] = form.draft_json(request)


# in template
<script>
    var draft_data = JSON.parse('{{ draft_json|safe }}');
    $scope.title = draft_data.title
</script>
```

The point here is to render and parse data using json format.
A much better way is to use ajax instead of passing draft data from the backend to avoid mixing js code with template rendered content.

Comment: This is a good idea as if the data was to come from another location via ajax form it could easily update the page contents. Nice 1